# Regex for matching whole words that contain dots

Tags: .net, regex

In the following sentence:

**I woke up in 5 p.m. today**

I want to match the **5 p.m.**. 
This pattern works:

```
5 p\.m\.
```

But I wanted it to match whole words only (so 5 p.m.us won't be matched).
So I used this pattern:

```
\b5 p\.m\.\b
```

But this didn't work because of the dot.

What will be the simplest regex to solve this? Can I define a zero-width match (\b style) that doesn't care if the character is a word character or not, only if it is a space or the end\beginning of the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead and lookbehind, which is a zero-width match, to do it. A regex like `(?<=^|\s)5 p\.m\.(?=\s|$)` means "Start of the string or a space character, followed by '5 p.m.' followed by anything which is a space character or end of string."

Comment: I'm trying to replace full word using this...but facing one more problem.. I'm trying to replace **the.** with **THE.** and it is replacing other words(them, then etc) also...

Answer (score 4):

Well, for that specific example, a simple one would be:

```
\b5 p\.m\.\B
```

But I doubt that would work very well in more complex source texts.

This article on [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) may be of help.