# Regex for Matching A Whole Word Containing Special Characters in VBA

Tags: regex, vba

I am trying to use `Regex` in `VBA` to match a whole word containing a hyphen and numbers. I know the `\b` would not work because it only set alphabetic boundaries.

Can this be done in `Regex` in `VBA`?

```
rx.Pattern = "[a-z][a-z][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]"
```

EDIT: I am sorry if I wasn't clear enough. My pattern has the following format "AA2-11". I want to match that whole string, that is why I can't use rx.pattern = "[a-z][a-z][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]" because that will hit a match if you have for example "AA2-11-4", while I just want "AA2-11"

Comment: [How to Use Regular Expressions in Visual Basic](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html)

Comment: Will the hyphen come first or the number?

Comment: Can you please include some of the words in your question ?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly are you asking. I had to re-read it many times but every time I understood something else so I had to delete my answer. Can you please give some examples as @Sniffer requested?

Comment: I am sorry if I wasn't clear enough. My pattern has the following format "AA2-11". I want to match that whole string, that is why I can't use rx.pattern = "[a-z][a-z][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]" because that will hit a match if you have for example "AA2-11-4", while I just want "AA2-11".

Comment: no worries :) simply update your question with some samples you want.

Comment: Your examples now make sense. I have posted the answer. Now check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

**MORE FOLLOWUP**

> Thanks for updating your answer, however I am afraid that it doesn't work. Let's say my document has for example AA12-12,AB14-26. The first occurence is not matched.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim regString As String
    Dim myRegExp As RegExp

    regString = "AA12-12#AB14-26"                     '<~~ Matches
    'regString = "#AA12-12,AB14-26#"                  '<~~ Matches
    'regString = "AA2-11 is a sample string"          '<~~ Matches

    'regString = "This is a sample AA2-11-11"         '<~~ Doesn't Match
    'regString = "This is a sample AA2-11-11 string"  '<~~ Doesn't Match
    'regString = "This is a sample AA2-11-11 string"  '<~~ Doesn't Match

    regString = " " & regString & " "

    Set myRegExp = New RegExp

    With myRegExp
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\b[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{1,}-\d{2,}\b(?=[^-])"
        If myRegExp.Test(regString) Then
            Debug.Print "Found"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Not Found"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Or like this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim regString As String
    Dim myRegExp As RegExp
    Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim myMatch As Match

    regString = "AA12-12,AB14-26"             '<~~ Matches
    'regString = "#AA12-12,AB14-26#"     '<~~ Matches
    'regString = "AA2-11 is a sample string"          '<~~ Matches

    'regString = "This is a sample AA2-11-11"         '<~~ Doesn't Match
    'regString = "This is a sample AA2-11-11 string"  '<~~ Doesn't Match
    'regString = "This is a sample AA2-11-11 string"  '<~~ Doesn't Match

    regString = " " & regString & " "

    Set myRegExp = New RegExp

    With myRegExp
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\b[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{1,}-\d{2,}\b(?=[^-])"

        Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(regString)

        For Each myMatch In myMatches
            Debug.Print myMatch.Value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The second procure is what I was looking for. Thanks much!

Comment: Both are same. The only difference is the `.IgnoreCase = True` :)

Comment: Hmmm, I just noticed that the Pattern you have suggested would not work if you have a long string. See in my case I am assigning regString to the content of a word document, regString = ActiveDocument.Range.Txt ,  I suspect because the caret and the sigil would not work in this case.

Comment: @Jeanno: Updated the answer. Let's see If I can come up with something better

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, however I am afraid that it doesn't work. Let's say my document has for example AA12-12,AB14-26. The first occurence is not matched. (Please note I am using For Each mtch In myRegExp.Execute(regString) ) . I think my problem is similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721982/regex-for-matching-whole-words-that-contain-dots?rq=1 but I have hyphens instead of dots, but I can't an error when I try to use the pattern suggested

Comment: @Jeanno: Check More Followup. :) Go on.. hit me with more exceptions :D

Comment: @Jeanno: Phew! That's music to my ears :D