# Regex - Find matching words AND dots that don't begin with prefix

Tags: regex

Similar to [Regex - Find all matching words that that don't begin with a specific prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308334/regex-find-all-matching-words-that-that-dont-begin-with-a-specific-prefix), and may be similar to [Regex for matching whole words that contain dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721982/regex-for-matching-whole-words-that-contain-dots)

I need to find all instances of "`somehost`" that doesn't start with "`com.`"

Specifically, I'm looking to change instances of "somehost" in the `address` but not the `contract`:

```
<endpoint address="https://subsite.somehost.com/someservice.svc" ... 
    contract="com.somehost.subsite.someservice.MyServiceSoap" />
<endpoint address="https://othersub.somehost.com/anotherservice.svc"  ...
    contract="com.somehost.othersub.anotherservice.MyOtherServiceSoap" />
```

Adapting the "(not girl)friend" example in the [first linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308334/regex-find-all-matching-words-that-that-dont-begin-with-a-specific-prefix), I've tried:

```
\b(?!com\.)[\w\.]*somehost\b
```

Which will match `subsite.somehost`, `othersub.somehost`, and `.somehost`, which also doesn't help at all if I want to just replace the `somehost` part.  Looks like the period (`.`) is screwing things up...

*(In my case, I do have access to lookbehinds)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this negative lookbehind:

```
[\w-]+\.(?<!com\.)somehost(?:\.[\w-]+)+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yA5iJ9/1)

i.e. use lookbehind `(?<!com\.)` just before `somehost` in your pattern.